# showing pictures in android for a specific time

Tags: android, camera

hey every body,
i am making an android app which interacts with camera. i want that after i capture an image it stays on screen for some specific time like 20 sec then after 20 sec the camera starts running again. at the moment i am only able to take the pictures and as soon as i take a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) that will help you to show pic for a defined duration.

Comment: thanx for helping :) saved me alot of time